# Spring Framework - Integration with old Java webapp

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a 10-year-old Java webapp, and I would like to introduce some new technology into the project. One of the things I would like to start doing is dependency injection. I know the Spring Framework has the capability to do dependency injection, but I am having a hard time integrating the framework into the old project.

Could someone provide an example of what I would have to change in my web.xml, other files I would have to add, and other changes I would need to make? I want the smallest Spring footprint while still being bale to do dependency injection.

There are a lot of examples online about *starting* a new project using Spring, but I can't find any about *integrating* Spring into an old project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to start by adding a context loader listener into your web.xml, along with the locations of the Spring configuration XML files.

You should configure the Spring `DispatcherServlet` to accept all URLs that you wish for it to handle.

You should write Controllers to bind and validate HTTP requests, call services, add data to `ModelAndView` for rendering, and map JSPs to success/failure views as needed.

You should put interfaces in front of your service and persistence tiers.  Move implementations into implementation classes that Spring can inject.

Leverage Spring AOP for security and transactions and logging as needed.

Comment: This helped, thanks. I got Spring to run on my server startup and initialize the classes I defined in applicationContext.xml. I think Spring might be too heavy for just dependency injection though. I can't inject onto a class without also including that class as a Spring bean, though, and that is presenting it's own problems.

Comment: Right, Spring can't inject it unless it's under its control.  Shouldn't be that big an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing new technology at a project wont make it faster\better, unless you introduce the new technology to all parts of the project. The idea behind DI is to lose dependencies between objects. The project probably is tightly coupled, so you'd have to rewrite at least parts of the thing. Depending on the size, this can be a monster to beat - ask yourself if this is worth it, if it has any positive effect on the project other than introducing new technology.

The reason why there are little to none tutorials about integrating DI container into an old project is quite simple: it usually doesn't make any sense. Either you use the pattern in all places, or none at all. The bastard child that would be creating by mixing both would be a horror to maintain. I'd really advise you think about **why**  you want to introduce a DI container into that 10 year project. Unless there is a real good reason for doing it (and you are happy with rewriting a lot of code) don't do it.

Comment: I disagree with this: It's not about making the app faster; it's about structuring it in such a way that it can be better in the future.  In my experience, Spring is especially good at taking on parts of an app without requiring that it be rewritten all or none.

Comment: I don't really see the point in doing that. Basically, you will have two applications running side by side which just happen to share some code/data. Now imagine a developer who only worked on the DI side of the project and now needs to fix something on the other side and assumes that it also is DI. If you think the usage of DI will make the structure of the app better, take the time to refactor it. The logic won't change so it should be able to do it in a fast manner.

Comment: It's an old web app.  It might not be layered well; it might be hard to test and extend.  There are a lot of reasons for doing it.  And of course when the refactored app was complete and proven to match the old one you'd retire the older app.